# Angular 2 temlate with Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I like to make `ngFor` loop in Angular 2 on template with `Observable` but I am getting this error:

`ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

This is the Plunker that is trowing the error:

[ngFor in template](https://plnkr.co/edit/6gOwLVHDZclrUPJrdTvP?p=preview)

```html
<template ngFor let-itemz [ngForOf]="item">
  <div>
    {{itemz.title}} | {{itemz.type}}
  </div>
</template>
```

I know that the code in constructor can be confusing, but this is just the short version of the bigger application that I have.

I cannot convert the Observable in Array, I have to use Observable.

The question is: Can I make template `ngFor` loop with Observable or the only thing that I can use is Array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [async pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html) which will subscribe and extract data for you behind the scene:

```html
<template ngFor let-itemz [ngForOf]="item | async">
  <div>
    {{itemz.title}} | {{itemz.type}}
  </div>
</template>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/imWRlthCOss0HmgwDEqC?p=preview

Comment: You where 45 seconds faster, you will get the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use async pipe to print Observeable:

```
 <div *ngFor="let itemz of item | async">
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/FAJCUKVPOlxulszdrZOU?p=preview

GoodLuck!